# Are Sharpoint Online and Sharepoint 2019 same?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We are integrating with Sharepoint 2013 currently using REST api at our customer location. We used the foundation version to test out our integration locally in dev environment.

They are planning to upgrade to Sharepoint 2019 and because there is no free/foundation version for Sharepoint 2019, would like to know if we can test out the integration with Sharepoint Online (as we have a subscription).

Basically, is the REST API same or does it work the same way between Sharepoint 2019 and Office 365 SharePoint online?

Answer (score 0):

The rest api works the same way in sp2019 and sharepoint online. You can test it in SharePoint Online for your on-premise environment.

And in fact you can get the evaluation key for SharePoint 2019 which lasts for 180 days. It shall be an easier option for you. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57462